# Android App killed state local notification not receiving - specifically Chinese rom devices

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

1. Alarm Manager - (better) not working in specific devices if app is not running
2. Work Manager - if app is not running nothing happening
3. Job scheduler - same if app is not running nothing happening

Comment: Please, add your code in the question.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question?

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com/